# 100.0% interrupts on one core

Tags: linux, cpu

Why `interrupts` doesn't spread across all cores?

```
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,100.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 25.2%us, 32.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 12.6%id, 26.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  3.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 29.0%us, 15.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 29.3%id, 26.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  : 16.0%us, 21.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 34.3%id, 27.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  : 26.0%us, 14.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 33.7%id, 25.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  : 15.0%us, 15.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 44.2%id, 25.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  : 13.0%us, 13.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 42.2%id, 31.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  9.7%us, 11.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 56.3%id, 23.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  : 13.0%us, 12.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.2%id, 25.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  9.6%us,  7.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 69.1%id, 13.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  8.9%us,  7.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 54.8%id, 28.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
```

without any apparent reason my server start working bad, after checking top I noticed that only one core handles 100% interrupts.

cat /proc/interrupts

```
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       CPU8       CPU9       CPU10      CPU11      
   0:        213          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
   8:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
   9:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
  16:        557          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb6, uhci_hcd:usb7, uhci_hcd:usb8
  17:    4373632      89953          0          0          0   10737111          0          0          0          0          0   22943776   IO-APIC-fasteoi   firewire_ohci
  19:         48          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb3, uhci_hcd:usb4, uhci_hcd:usb5
  24:        378          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   nouveau
  34:        232          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   hda_intel
  64:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      aerdrv, PCIe PME
  65:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      aerdrv, PCIe PME
  66:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      aerdrv, PCIe PME
  67:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  68:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  69:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  70:   27356052          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mpt2sas0
  71:     360910          0          0          0      10388     366203          0     660341          0          0          0    1011704   PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
  72:          7          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
  73:    3223115          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-0
  74:          6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth1
  75:    3573711          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth1-TxRx-0
  76:          6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2
  77:    3548069          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-TxRx-0
  78:          6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth3
  79:    3290681          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth3-TxRx-0
  80:          6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth4
  81:    3319709          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth4-TxRx-0
  82:          7          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth5
  83:    3294914          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth5-TxRx-0
  84:        223          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      hda_intel
  85:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  86:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  87:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  88:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  89:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  90:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  91:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  92:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
 NMI:      20083      11292       9555      10288       8470       9085       7319       7726       6190       6286       5305       5966   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:   12625312   12863741   12757467   12819307   12735818   12636631   12594014   12340042   12351248   11896407   11976946   11309230   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:      20083      11292       9555      10288       8470       9085       7319       7726       6190       6286       5305       5966   Performance monitoring interrupts
 IWI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
 RES:    2102300   11881309   11859706   12689803   11274676   10461216    9626798    8188722    7976358    6329291    6344685    4528014   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:     732819   20016455      15519      15361      17958      23935      23377      43079      40287     108860      70814     257653   Function call interrupts
 TLB:       7589      72270      46673      99284      46373     121129      43286     101506      34109      78720      28570      70600   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:         44         44         44         44         44         44         44         44         44         44         44         44   Machine check polls
 ERR:          0
 MIS:          0
```

cat /proc/interrupts indicates that all network nics are handled by CPU0, I guess here is the problem.

Network is configured with BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer3+4"

What I've tried:

1. running irqbalance
2. reboot

Answer (score 0):

Check interrupt CPU affinity with:

```
cat /proc/irq/70/smp_affinity
```

I chose 70 because it is tied to mpt2sas0, the storage card driver. You may want to repeat the check for all other divers too, expecially network cards if you are servicing a lot of traffic.

You want that setting to report the value *ffffffff* because that means that all CPU can service this interrupt.

You can follow this [document](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-cpu-irq.html) from RedHat as a reference.

Comment: That doc is outdated... ` Value too large for defined data type` I can only set six characters long ffffff did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [irqbalance](https://linux.die.net/man/1/irqbalance).